# group by a column & count total foreign relations within prisma

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma

#### tl;dr

the problem
[image: An excalidraw representation of the problem]

#### db schema.

I have two prisma models,

- `Browser` with `name` and `version`  & `id`
- `Redirect` with `browserID` (that has a `1-m` relation with Browser [a single browser type can be assigned to many redirects]), some other similar 1-m `xyzID`.

#### what i wanna do.

I want to

- group browsers by name (say `(opera, 12.0)` & `(opera, 10.0)` can live under the same group `opera`) and I wanna sum the total redirects that are attached to the browser. So, Using the same opera example if `(opera, 12.0)` has 10 redirects & `(opera, 10.0)` has 15 redirects. My count should be 25.
- In the same query. I also want to filter by Redirect ID. So, I still want to count by grouping but only count those browsers who are connected to my Redirect.

The final result should be like,

```
[
   { name: "opera", count: 25 }, // opera 12.0's 10 redirects & opera 10.0's 15 redirects
    // ...
]
```

#### what i've tried.

- It's not possible to do this with prisma normally as much I've tried so I attempted to `queryRaw`. My query looked like this but it doesn't work.

```sql
SELECT
  "public"."Browser"."name",
  COUNT(*) as count
FROM
  "public"."Browser"
JOIN
  "public"."Redirect" ON "public"."Browser"."id" = "public"."Redirect"."browserID"
WHERE
  "public"."Redirect"."id" = ${input.id} AND "public"."Redirect"."id" IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  "public"."Browser"."name"
```

- I've also tried `DISTINCT` & stuff but this doesn't work either.

If anyone knows this stuff, let me know!

Comment: You're using `prisma` ryt? You can use [groupBy](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/aggregation-grouping-summarizing) to perform **aggregation along with filtering**. Did you try it? Also, I believe you have set up the relationships between the `Browser` and `Redirect` models in your Prisma schema.

Comment: Hi @mandy8055, I definitely tried to use `groupBy` to solve this. Unfortunately, The result isn't quite what I expected. I just realized, I framed the question wrong and I apologize for it.  Instead of counting the number of unique fields so say two browser rows exist (opera, 1.0) and (opera, 2.0). The group by name (opera) and count would return 2. I want to get the sum of redirects that are attached to each browser of same name and show that as count. So If (opera, 1.0) has 10 redirects and (opera, 2.0) has 15 redirects. I want to still group by name but my count should be 25.

Comment: Oh I thought we could do it. Let me add my approach. You can try and I can see you got it working so all good. `const result = await prisma.browser.groupBy({
  by: ["name", "version"],
  where: {
    redirects: {
      some: {
        id: input.id,
      },
    },
  },
}).sum({
  redirects: true,
});

console.log(result);`

Comment: I attempted your solution mandy. It's not possible to chain functions in prisma so `.groupBy({ ... }).sum({ ... })` would be invalid. I'm quite sure this wouldn't be possible natively in prisma so I think the solution left would be to use `.queryRaw()`. Still, thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay! I think "groupBy" & counting of foreign fields is not possible using prisma without using `queryRaw`. To achieve the above result. I wrote the following raw query & it works as expected.

```sql
SELECT
  "public"."Browser"."name" AS name,
  COUNT("public"."Redirect"."id") AS count
FROM
  "public"."Browser"
JOIN
  "public"."Redirect" ON "public"."Browser".id = "public"."Redirect"."browserID"
WHERE
  "public"."Redirect"."urlID" = ${input.id}
GROUP BY
  "public"."Browser"."name"
ORDER BY
  count DESC
```

The result,

```json
[
  { name: 'Firefox', count: 27n },
  { name: 'Opera', count: 25n },
  { name: 'Chrome', count: 20n },
  { name: 'IE', count: 16n },
  { name: 'Safari', count: 13n }
]
```